# В автосалоне / НА авиасалоне МАКС

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Почему мы говорим ***в*** автосалоне, но — ***на*** авиасалоне МАКС?

Это происходит, потому что **на авиасалоне МАКС** означает некоторое конкретное событие, а не место? Что-то вроде, как говорят, "на празднике"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Автосалон* в бытовом понимании - крытое торговое сооружение (**в** нём). *Авиасалон* можно трактовать как *мероприятие* типа выставки (при официальном упоминании именно это определяет предлог: **на** выставке-продаже, именуемой авиасалоном), а в буквальном смысле можно трактовать как открытое пространство типа аэродрома или стадиона (в обоих случах употребляется "на").

Answer (score 1):

Если бы русский язык поменьше захламляли иностранными "словами" (ибо на деле, в данном случае, это даже не слово, а произношение-написание оного), значения которых малопонятны, из-за чужеродной корневой составляющей оных, то таких вопросов у русскоговорящих людей было бы поменьше.

Суть же заключается в происхождении "слова" "салон". Есть французское слово прародитель salon, которое может иметь несколько значений, а именно: гостиная, лавка или выставка. Таким образом, в первоначальном, во французском значении (мы же без чужих слов никуда) "в автосалоне" будет иметь значение нахождения в помещении, где продают самовозы, а "на авиасалоне" будет подразумеваться именно нахождение на выставке самолётов. Однако можно сказать и "в авиасалоне", подразумевая некое большое помещение, где продают самолёты.